# OpenCV ConvertTo Float Error

Tags: opencv

The test image has 3 channels.
The following produces an error.

```
cv::Mat temp = cv::imread(filename.c_str());
cv::Mat_<float> temp2;
temp.convertTo(temp2, CV_32F);
```

OpenCV(3.4.1-dev) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create, file /home/jason/projects/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1199

This also produces the same error.

```
cv::Mat temp = cv::imread(filename.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::Mat_<float> temp2;
temp.convertTo(temp2, CV_32FC3);
```

Why does it keep failing?
Thanks,

Comment: If the image is a 3 channel image then you need to create `temp2` as: `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> temp2`.

Comment: Vec3f worked. As a test, I then tried to convert the Vec3f to float.
cv::Mat_<float> temp3
temp2.convertTo(temp3, CV_32FC3);
But that failed. So is there no way to have Mat_<float>?

Comment: One more comment, when showing temp2 image, it is mostly white with some light blue pixels spread throughout.

Comment: You need to read this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html. But to answer your questions: **1)** `convertTo` function does not change the number of channels, only the data type (depth). **2)** `Mat_<float>` creates single channel image of type float. `Mat_<Vec3f>` creates 3 channel image of type float. **3)** You can only display images of type `unsigned char`, any other data type will automatically be typecasted to `unsigned char` before displaying.